# How to make a layer fade to transparent?

Tags: post-processing, filters, effect, layers

I have two layers of the same image. The first layer underneath is the original, while the other on top of it is a copy of the original, but with some applied effect or filter.

I would like to make this copied layer have a tapered transparency to it (maybe through its alpha channel) so that the effect that it contains appears on top of the original layer underneath it in a faded, gradual way, rather than all at once replacing the original in the flattened visible image. How to do this in Gimp especially, but can answer for other software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- On the top layer, add a layer mask (`Layer > Mask > Add layer mask`, and initialize to white).
- Create a black to white gradient on the mask (black is the transparent side). When doing so, if you click near the middle of the line, you get a cursor that allows you to tune how the gradient changes, and therefore how the top layer fades.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to use [Layer Mask](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Layer_Masks/). Add the mask to edited layer, (eventually fill it with black ) then apply some gradient to the mask. When play with mask use black, white (and gray). This make the layer with mask transparent (black) or nontransparent (white).

P.S. Those things are for Photoshop, but I suppose in GIMP will be similar.